# Example of a Protocol Buffer being sent in http by java

Tags: java, http, serialization, binary, protocol-buffers

You set content-type to application/x-protobuf, then you serialize the protocol buffer, and then put the binary data into an http body. Send it to server/client!

What is a standard way to program such a task in java?

Comment: Standard? `HttpUrlConnection`. Not standard but better? [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/).

Comment: That is definitely helpful. It seems you'd use the getOutputStream()

Comment: Personally I'd use the retrofit protobuf converters. Probably `wire`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Jetty HTTP client, it's as easy as

```
ContentResponse response = httpClient.newRequest("http://domain.com/upload")
        .method(HttpMethod.POST)
        .content(new InputStreamContentProvider(new FileInputStream("serialized_protocol.bin")), "application/x-protobuf")
        .send();
```

See http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.x/http-client-api.html#http-client-content